# Bukkit - The method playerAdd(Player, String) is undefined for the type Permission

Tags: java, bukkit

I have an error on `playerAdd` under:

```
if(!player.hasPermission("*")){
  String permission = "*";
  perms.playerAdd(player, permission);
}
```

The error is

```
Bukkit - The method playerAdd(Player, String) is undefined for the type Permission`
```

It references:

```
public static Permission perms = null;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private boolean setupPermissions() {
    RegisteredServiceProvider<Permission> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Permission.class);
    perms = rsp.getProvider();
    return perms != null;
}
```

My APIs are:

- Paperspigot
- Vault - dependancy
- PermissionsEX

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Lightspeed360 give a player a permission

Comment: So `perms.playerAdd(player, "permhere");` gives said player said permission? Is there another method or is it only `playerADD`? Is there not any permissionAdd? Oh and can you give me the error?

Comment: @Lightspeed360 The method playerAdd(Player, String) is undefined for the type Permission

Comment: That means the method doesn't exist. . .

Comment: @Lightspeed360 but it does and thats my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108662/discussion-between-lightspeed360-and-jake-f).

Comment: Did you import the PermissionsEx's Permission or the Bukkit one?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with PermissionsEX, you will have to add the PermissionsEX.jar to the Java Build Path. Then simply put this in there:

```
ru.tehkode.permissions.bukkit.PermissionsEx.getUser(player).addPermission("permhere");
```

I don't know how you can do it in another way.